# How to link two autocompletes with vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js

I have two autocompletes in my component and the second autocomplete array items  depends on the first has any data.

-- first

```
          <v-col cols="12" md="1">
        <v-autocomplete
          v-model="cliente.estado"
          :loading="isLoading"
          :search-input.sync="search"
          hide-no-data
          hide-selected
          auto-select-first
          :items="listaEstado"
          item-text="sigla"
          label="Estado"
          return-object
          v-on:change="setEstado"
        ></v-autocomplete>
```

-- second

```
            <v-autocomplete
          v-model="cliente.municipio"
          :loading="isLoading"
          :search-input.sync="searchM"
          hide-no-data
          hide-selected
          auto-select-first
          :items="itemsMunicipio"
          return-object
          item-text="sigla"
          label="Munícipo"
        ></v-autocomplete>
```

After the change event, my "itemsMunicipio" recieves the data from server but the component doesn't render.
Any tips from this problem?

Comment: Hi, could your provide your on-change method and how you get itemsMunucipio (data or computed)?

Comment: Hi David! I solved the problem using the lazy tag. I also missed the declaration of the 'searchM' in my data role. i'll post the resolution.

Comment: Are you just trying to show the second one once the first one has its data set?

Comment: Hi @maxshuty! Yep. They both are initialized with an empty array. My second autocomplete recieves data from server, after the 'change' event fired by de first autocomplete. I solved this problem with the lazy tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding the lazy tag with my v-autocomplete. I also declared a new variable for the search inside 'watch' property.

```
            <v-lazy>
          <v-autocomplete
            v-model="cliente.municipio"
            :loading="isLoading"
            :search-input.sync="searchM"
            hide-no-data
            auto-select-first
            :items="itemsMunicipio"
            return-object
            item-text="descricao"
            label="Municipo"
          ></v-autocomplete>
        </v-lazy>
```